# How to configure id editor in my server without Oauth

Tags: oauth, mapping, openstreetmap

I'm new in Web mapping, I need web map editor. I found the [iD Editor](https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD) but I couldn't configure it to my own osm server! I don't know how is it working with API and Oauth.

How to configure the iD editor in my server without Oauth and how to create API?

Thanks.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/47774/how-to-configure-id-editor-on-own-server-without-oauth

Answer (score 5):

The [openstreetmap-website](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/CONFIGURE.md) documentation has a excellent tutorial of how to use an editor with the openstreetmap-api.

The example of the doc is using the Potlatch 2 editor, but you can do the same process for registering and configuring iD (id_key) and the website/Notes (oauth_key).

Do the following:

- Log into your Rails Port instance - e.g. http://localhost:3000
- Click on your user name to go to your user page
- Click on "my settings" on the user page
- Click on "oauth settings" on the My settings page
- Click on 'Register your application'.
- Unless you have set up alternatives, use Name: "Local iD" and URL: "http://localhost:3000"
- Check the 'modify the map' box.
- Everything else can be left with the default blank values.
- Click the "Register" button
- On the next page, copy the "consumer key"
- Edit config/application.yml in your rails tree
- Uncomment and change the "oauth_key" configuration value
- Restart your rails server

An example excerpt from application.yml:

```
# Default editor
default_editor: "id"
# OAuth consumer key for iD
id_key: "8lFmZPsagHV4l3rkAHq0hWY5vV3Ctl3oEFY1aXth"
```

To use the iD editor you need to use OAuth authorization, otherwise, you can use the [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) editor which you can choose a base authentication.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Default editor
default_editor: "id"
# OAuth consumer key for iD
oauth_key: "8lFmZPsagHV4l3rkAHq0hWY5vV3Ctl3oEFY1aXth"
```

to change:

```
# OAuth consumer key for iD
id_key: "8lFmZPsagHV4l3rkAHq0hWY5vV3Ctl3oEFY1aXth"
```

Answer (score 0):

`application.yml` has been refactored to `settings.yml` but you will need to create a `settings.local.yml` to override it configurations.